# Execution order within JS script

Tags: javascript, html, api

I am currently trying to create a website which gets its information live from an API. For this, I am now trying to change a variable based on the API call.
while playing around with the JS code I realized, that the order of execution is not as expected.

```js
var url = "https://api.worldoftanks.eu/wot/globalmap/clanprovinces/?application_id=bbdd3a54ffe280ff581db61299acab9c&clan_id=500071433&fields=province_id%2C+daily_revenue%2C+province_name%2C+revenue_level";


var a = 10;

fetch(url)
.then(res => res.json())
.then((out) => {
changeProvinceName(out.data[500071433][0]);
})
.catch(err => { throw err });

function changeProvinceName(json){
  console.log(json.province_name);
  document.getElementById("province_name1").innerHTML = "<h2>"+json.province_name+"</h2>";
  province=""+json.province_name;
  a = 20;
}

console.log(a);
```

I am not sure why it is creating the console.log(a) first and then gets the API request.

Is there a possibility where I can run the API call first in order to use the modified value of a.

For all the code including HTML and CSS have a look at my [Github repo](https://github.com/Ironlors/WOT-CW-Dashboard/tree/development/html) for this project.

Comment: `fetch()` is **asynchronous**. It starts the operation and returns immediately. The functions passed to `.then()` will be called when the HTTP request completes.

Comment: So how would I make the script wait until the Request is completed so I can work with the new data?

Comment: everything inside the `.then` happens after the request completes, while everything outside the `.then` happens *while the request is happening*.  this is what makes asynchronous code able to be non blocking.

Comment: You don't. Instead you do your work *inside* the `.then()` callback (or by calling other functions from there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fetch(url) is `async`. In javascript first all synchronous code is executed then after this is finished the `async` code will be executed in the [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop).

Because console.log(a); is synchronous first this will be executed and after this the async promise.then(). Also take a look into [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which is a Javascript construct which helps to deal with async code.

You can run your code also in a .then() of the promises like this:

```
fetch(url)
.then(res => {
 a = 10;
 return res;
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then((out) => {
changeProvinceName(out.data[500071433][0]);
})
```

Here is another example of how you can influence a variable during the execution of a promise. A understanding of how promises work is required though:

```js
let hey = new Promise((res, rej) => {
  res(5);
});

hey.then((res) => {
  res += 5;
  return res;
}).then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
});
```